# How does Arduino Ethernet library handle reconnections

Tags: arduino, ethernet, esp8266wifi

I would like to find out if the standard Arduino Ethernet library handles possible re-connections automatically like ESP8266WiFi library does with wifi.

If for some reason the Ethernet connection, that has been established with

```
Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
```

is lost do I have to establish a new connection in my sketch?

Comment: it can't be lost. it is still one device on network if the cable is not connected

Comment: I think this conversation explains the issue in detail: [link] https://forum.arduino.cc/t/reconnecting-to-ethernet/100652

Comment: for unplugged cable there is now Ethernet.linkStatus(); with example in IDE Examples menu